# Span of Null Space of A

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Apologies for the brief nature of this question, but it is something that I don't think was clarified in a previous post on this topic - [Finding a spanning set for a null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202617/finding-a-spanning-set-for-a-null-space).

When we say that the null space of the matrix $A$ is equal to the span of some set of vectors:

$N(A) = span(\vec v_1, \vec v_2,$   $... \vec v_n)$

Are we effectively saying that:

$A(\vec v_1) + A(\vec v_2) +$ $... A(\vec v_n) = \vec 0$

Comment: @Surb Add "and that $v_1,v_2$ are in $N(A)$" to your "unless". We could have $Av_1+_v_2=0$ but neither $Av_1=0$ nor $Av_2=0$

Comment: @Surb I have edited the question slightly so that the dimensionality isn't a factor. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be precise, $$N(A)=\text{Span}\{v_1,...,v_n\},$$
indeed implies that $$Av_1+\cdot +Av_n=0,$$
or even that for all $\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n\in\mathbb R$ (if you work in a $\mathbb R-$vector space) that $$\alpha _1Av_1+...+\alpha _nAv_n=0.$$

But the converse doesn't hold. If $N(A)$ has $n$ dimension, that $v_1,...,v_n\in N(A)$ and that there are free, then indeed $N(A)=\text{Span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. But $Av_1+...+Av_n=0$ just allow you to conclude that $v_1+...+v_n\in N(A)$ and unfortunately nothing more.

Comment: $\alpha _1Av_1+...+\alpha _nAv_n=0$ ... I think this is in fact what I was originally looking for. Where $\alpha_i$ is some constant mutliplied by $Av_i$ (the vector resulting from the matrix $A$ mutliplied by the vector $v_i$). This is how I would typically think of a linear combination.

Answer (score 2):

When you talk about the span of S, you speak of the collection of all linear combinations of S. In particular, to speak of the span of $N(A)$, we look at the linear combinations of the items in the null space of A. These combinations are in the span (as $N(A)$ is a subspace of the parent vector space). Suppose $S = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\} \subset N(A)$. Then $\mathrm{span}(S) = \sum_{1 \leq n} c_j v_j.$